# How to separate aesthetics of two different geom_lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a liine on the x axis which is basically a bunch of zeros and ones. Ones are green and zeros are red. When I try to do that, the color_scale_gradient of the ggplot basically colors on top of the line.

It looks like this

[image: wrong plot]

Where the line should be colored as follows:

[image: Desired plot]

colorbar is a vector of zeros and ones.

```
p <- ggplot(data1,aes(newx,newy, group = 1, colour=newy))+
    geom_line(size=1.5, show.legend = FALSE)+
    scale_colour_gradient(low="red2", high="green3") + 
    geom_line(data = colorFrame, aes(as.numeric(x)-5,as.numeric(ys), color = colorbar),size=3, show.legend = FALSE)+
    xlim(0,1300)

p <- p + 
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),  
      axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'black'), 
      axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(colour = 'black')) + 
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 12, 1), limits = c(-1, 12), expand = c(0,0))
```

Comment: Don't map `y` to your data, just set `y=1` in your `aes()`

Comment: You may also want to use `colour = factor(newy)` with `scale_colour_manual(values = c("red2", "green3"))` to treat the colors as discrete rather than continuous.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create two subplots and stitch them together. I use `cowplot` and `theme_void` here, but really the second plot below could look however you want it to.

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, group = 1, colour=y)) +
  geom_line(size=1.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="red2", high="green3") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),  
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'black'), 
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(colour = 'black')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 12, 1), limits = c(-1, 12), expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(x = NULL)

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y = 0, colour=z)) +
  geom_line(size=1.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="red2", high="green3") +
  theme_void()

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, 
                   ncol = 1, 
                   rel_heights = c(1, .05),
                   align = 'v')
```

[image]

---

Data

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:50, 
                 y = runif(50, 0, 12), 
                 z = sample(c(0,1), 50, replace = TRUE))
```